# Bound quiver representation of matrix algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

I have been trying to write a bound quiver representation of each of the following algebras:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
K&0&0&0&0\\
K&K&0&0&0\\
K&0&K&0&0\\
K&0&K&K&0\\
K&K&K&K&K
\end{bmatrix},
B=\begin{bmatrix}
K&0&0&0&0\\
K&K&0&0&0\\
K&0&K&0&0\\
K&0&0&K&0\\
K&K&K&K&K
\end{bmatrix},
C=\begin{bmatrix}
K&0&0&0&0\\
0&K&0&0&0\\
K&K&K&0&0\\
K&0&0&K&0\\
K&K&K&K&K
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I would like to know whether my solution is correct or not.

---

I just consider the easiest quiver I can think of associated to each of the algebras:

[image]

There is a $K$-algebra homomorphism $\phi_*:KQ_*\to *$, $*=A,B,C$, for the three algebras each, defined in the natural way that maps $e_i$ to $E_{ii}$ and any arrow $i\to j$ to $E_{ij}$. Clearly $\phi_*$ is surjective since any matrix in the algebra has a preimage given by some path in the respective quiver. Now we decide the kernel of the homomorphisms.

For $A$, there are not paths $4\to 2$ or $3\to 2$, so the only relation generating the kernel is the commutativity: $\xi\alpha=\omega\tau\beta$. Clearly $\mathcal I_1:=\langle \xi\alpha-\omega\tau\beta\rangle\subseteq R_Q^2$ is admissible, since $Q_A$ is acyclic. Hence $A\cong KQ_A/\mathcal I_1$.

For $B$, similarly we only get the commutativity ones: $\eta\alpha=\xi\beta=\omega\gamma$. $\mathcal I_2:=\langle \eta\alpha-\xi\beta,\eta\alpha-\omega\gamma\rangle$ is also admissible. Hence $B\cong KQ_B/\mathcal I_2$.

For $C$, we also get the generating relation $\delta\alpha=\eta\gamma$. For the same reason $\mathcal I_3:=\langle \delta\alpha-\eta\gamma\rangle$ is admissible. Hence $C\cong KQ_C/\mathcal I_3$.

---

The relations seem to be just the commutativity, so I am wondering whether there is something wrong in the demonstration.

Thank you very much for your patience!